# Why doesn't my db.collection.insert work?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

I am encountering a weird issue here... 
After I seem to successfully insert some data into my `db.collection` I cant seem to get it to reflect using `db.collection.find().fetch()`.

Find below the code I insert into my chrome console:

```
merchantReviews.insert({merchantScore: "5.5"}, function() {
console.log("Review value successfully inserted");
});
```

This yields:

```
"9sd5787kj7dsd98ycnd"    
Review value successfully inserted
```

I think returned value `"9sd5787kj7dsd98ycnd"` is an indication of a successful db collection insert. Then when I run:

```
merchantReviews.find().fetch()
```

I get:

```
[]
```

Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

Looking forward to your help.

Comment: Are you running `merchantReviews.find().fetch()` on the client or on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here: either the insert fails on the server even though it passes on the client, or you haven't subscribed to your collection.

In case the `insert` fails on server (most likely due to insufficient permissions, if you have removed the `insecure` package but have not declared any `collection.allow` rules), the client code still returns the intended insert ID (in your case, `"9sd5787kj7dsd98ycnd"`). The callback is called once the server has confirmed that the insert has either failed or succeeded. If it has failed, the callback is called with a single error argument. To catch this, you can instead insert the document like this:

```js
merchantReviews.insert({merchantScore: "5.5"}, function(error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Review value successfully inserted");
  }    
});
```

If this still logs successful insert, then you haven't subscribed to the collection, and you have removed the `autopublish` package. You can read about Meteor publish-subscribe system [here](http://docs.meteor.com/api/pubsub.html). Basically, you have to `publish` the collection **in server-side code:**

```js
Meteor.publish('reviews', function () {
  return merchantReviews.find();
});
```

And in server code (or your js console) you need to subscribe to the collection with `Meteor.subscribe('reviews')`. Now calling `merchantReviews.find().fetch()` should return all documents in the collection.